# iPhone Dev - Storing and Retrieving Variables from App Delegate

Tags: iphone, variables, delegates

I have created a variable in my App Delegate and from my first View Controller, I am saving a value to the variable (in the App Delegate).

Here is how I'm saving the value to the variable in the App Delegate:

`MyAppDelegate *DelegateVar = TheValue;`

`NSLog(@"%@", DelegateVar);` // This NSLog outputs correct value

Later in the program, in a separate ViewController, I am trying to retrieve the value from the App Delegate. I am getting values that look to be pointers...

Here is how I'm trying to retrieve the value:

`MyAppDelegate *MyVar = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

`NSLog(@"%@", MyVar);` // outputs incorrect value

Anybody that has any input regarding my problem, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense. Why are you assigning a value to a pointer to your application's delegate in the first place? If you want to assign a value to an instance variable *inside* your delegate, then you need to do something completely different.

Comment: Okay... can you please give some idea about how to do this, or what might be the name of the process so that I can research it ?

Comment: Contrary to what you may have been lead to believe by many of the iPhone related books and blogs on the market, you need to actually learn C before you do anything else. None of this is going to make any sense to you until you do.

Comment: Thank you for fighting for truth and justice.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check the main XIB file to ensure the delegate is wired up to the application.

Second, try replacing `TheValue` in the first instance with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]` and see if you get the same incorrect value as you do later on.

Comment: When I switch `TheValue` with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate` , it does give me the same value `<MyAppDelegate: 0x3d1d620>` in both View Controllers - I'm guessing that value represents the address/something of the variable - so I really don't think I'm accessing it correctly the 2nd time through...

Comment: Another note, it is returning the same `<MyAppDelegate: 0x3d1d620>` every time I run the App, so I may not be accessing the data that I think I am accessing.